# Convexity of a homogeneous bivariate function and inequality by Beurling

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

I am currently trying to understand the proof of Theorem 1 in [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/arkiv-for-matematik/volume-3/issue-3/On-the-uniform-convexity-of-Lp-and-lp/10.1007/BF02589410.full) (On the uniform convexity of $L^p$ and $l^p$ spaces). I am only interested in the left hand side of the inequality (the right hand side corresponds to Clarkson's inequality)

The author states that when $1<p<2$, for $u,v\geq 0$ $$ \xi(u,v) = (u^{\frac 1p}+ v^{\frac 1p})^p + |u^{\frac 1p}-v^{\frac 1p}|^p $$ is convex. However, I don't understand the following argument that is made in the paper: $\xi(0,0)=0$, $\xi(u,v)=\xi(v,u)$ and $\xi(tu,tv)=t\xi(u,v)$ for $t>0$ *therefore* convexity of $\xi(u,1)$ is sufficient.

The author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2572411/convexity-of-a-function-of-two-variables-given-convexity-in-one-variable) mentions in a comment the same paper, and a comment responded that the result is "visually trivial".

Trying to blindly apply convexity inequalities doesn't yield much: $$\xi(t(x,y)+(1-t)(u,v))\leq t(t\xi(x,y)+(1-t)\xi(x,v))+(1-t)(t\xi(u,y)+(1-t)\xi(u,v))$$

How can the statement be proven ?

Comment: Are they proving convexity using the Hessian?

Comment: The paper only treats the convexity of $u\mapsto\xi(u,1)$, which is a simple matter of verifying that the second derivative is positive. There is no calculus done on $\xi$ itself

Comment: At a first guess, I think they would need to show convexity of $\xi$ at $(u,1)$, not just as a function of the first coordinate.

Comment: The author shows the convexity of $u\mapsto \xi(u,1)$ (this is unambiguous in the article, which is in open access) and says this is sufficient

Comment: Using the hessian does indeed show convexity without too much hassle: since $h: u \mapsto \xi(u,1)$ is convex, $h''\geq 0$ and the hessian depends only on $h''$ (not $h,h'$) if my calculations are correct. I'm still interested in why the author states this this way

Comment: The only approach I can imagine at the moment is to try and check if the Hessian of $(u,v) \mapsto v \xi( {u \over v}, 1)$ is convex. (Visually trivial does not cut it for me in this instance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u,v>0$, note that $\xi(u,v) = v \xi({u \over v},1)$.

Then ${\partial \xi(u,v) \over \partial u} = {\partial \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u}$,

${\partial \xi(u,v) \over \partial v} = \xi({u \over v},1)- {u \over v} {\partial \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u}$,

${\partial^2 \xi(u,v) \over \partial u^2} = {1 \over v} {\partial^2 \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u^2}$,

${\partial^2 \xi(u,v) \over \partial v \partial u} = -{u \over v^2} {\partial^2 \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u^2}$,

${\partial^2 \xi(u,v) \over \partial v^2} = -{u \over v^2} {\partial \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u} + {u \over v^2} {\partial \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u} + {u^2 \over v^3} {\partial^2 \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u^2} = {u^2 \over v^3} {\partial^2 \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u^2} $.

Hence
$H_\xi(u,v) = {1 \over v^3} {\partial^2 \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u^2} \begin{bmatrix} v^2 & -uv \\ -uv & u^2
\end{bmatrix}$, and if ${\partial^2 \xi ( {u \over v},1) \over \partial u^2}  \ge 0$ then $H_\xi(u,v) \ge 0 $ (as in positive semidefinite).

Convexity on $u,v \ge 0$ follows from continuity.